# Detect an event when user clicks enter on address bar Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

is there any way to detect if user clicks enter on address bar?

I am detecting browser refresh if user click ctrl + F5 or Ctrl + r,
but I want to detect when user just goes to address bar and hits enter.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
beforeunloadHandler(e) {
const r = "keyR"

if (e.code == "F5"
  || (e.ctrlKey && e.code == r)
  || (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.code == r)) {
         console.log('Refresh occurred')
 } else if (e.type === "beforeunload"
  || e.type === "unload") {
         console.log('Browser window is closed')
 }
```

Comment: I believe the only event you'll detect for that is the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: is there anyone i can differentiate between browser/tab close and click enter on address bar? both events are currently same beforeunload.

Comment: I do not think there is. Basically the `document` gets a `focusout` event when the user tabs to or clicks the address bar. At that point, the js in the document won't "hear" any events from the address bar (if they exist) because they are events of the browser application and not the page being displayed. The real question is "Why do you need to tell the difference?" If the user is leaving they are leaving. Does it really matter how they are leaving?

Comment: I have a backend code on the server side that needs to be executed only on browser close and not when user refreshes; cause that will be unnecessary call.